# Couldn't include plug-ins in servoy.target file

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I've attached a screenshot for the mentioned error.

**Screeshot:**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'not included'? What is happening? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I used GIT Repositories view to clone the open source Servoy projects  from the repositories , according to Servoy official Documentation( https://wiki.servoy.com/display/public/DOCS/Setting+Up ).Then I did 'Import Project' from Git to Java EE perspective. When I opened 'servoy.target' file , I was expecting the plugins to be included. But, I got plugins available rather than included. You can see the expected 'servoy.target' file results in the link provided above.

Answer (score 0):

You use a .target file to define a 'Target Platform' which appears in the Preferences in 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform'. You can then set that as the platform you are developing new plug-ins against.

Comment: I am explaining what the .target file is for. I think the compile errors are due to something else.

Answer (score 0):

From the [setup instructions](https://wiki.servoy.com/display/public/DOCS/Setting+Up) (this is in the quick start only, missing from detailed setup AFAICT):

> Make sure the entry for `${workspace_loc}/eclipse_target/libs_extra`
>   display `(x of x included)`, where `x` is equal to the number of
>   libraries (.jar files) in the libs_extra directory. If not, **force a
>   refresh** by selecting the entry, clicking Edit > Finish and then
>   Control-S to save the editor

(emphasis mine)